# Whether the object can be collected by GC

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Hi all: assuming I got the Class A and B:

```
class A {
    public string foo = "foo";
    public int a = 10;
    public double d = 3.14;
}

class B {
    public string s;
}

A a = new A();
B b = new B();

b.s = a.foo;

a = null;

// if GC occurs here...
```

My question is after **a** is set to null, whether it can be collected by GC at next GC trigger point even though b reference one of its fields, foo?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Side note: assigning to `null` isn't usually required, if `a` is just a local variable. The JIT and GC collaborate to know the lifetime of variables and so (if neither variable is referenced again), both `a` and `b` are eligible for collection at the `//if GC occurs here` line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is after a is set to null, whether it can be collected by GC at next GC trigger point even though b reference one of its fields, foo?

The value of `b.s` *happens* to have been set to `a.foo`, but that's just copying the value. After the assignment occurs, there's absolutely no connection between the instances of `A` and `B`. In particular, any changes to `a.foo` won't be visible via `b.s`.

So yes, the instance of `A` can be garbage collected.

Now, I suspect someone may talk about `string` being immutable. While this is true, it doesn't actually affect things. Suppose we had:

```
class A
{
    // We would never really use public fields, of course...
    public StringBuilder x;
}

class B
{
    public StringBuilder y;
}
```

Then:

```
A a = new A();
a.x = new StringBuilder("Foo");

B b = new B();
b.y = a.x;
b.y.Append("Bar");
Console.WriteLine(a.x); // Prints FooBar

a = null;
```

*Still*, the instance of B does not prevent the instance of A from being garbage collected - because again, assignment has just copied the value from `a.x` to `b.y`. That value is a reference to the `StringBuilder`, so modifying the contents of the `StringBuilder` via either field results in a change that is visible via the other field, but the fields don't actually "know" about each other.

Answer (score 1):

`B`'s `s` field referencing `A`'s `foo` field not `A`'s instance, also `A`'s `foo` field is an instance of `string`. `GC` will destroy it sometime but we don't know exactly when (but it'll). If you want this process immediately, force run `GC` by `GC.Collect()`. `A`'s instance will be destroyed.

*I'm working on an example now to prove my answer.* -Nevermind, Jon Skeet here :)